# print(f'"...") with float formatting

Tags: python, string, printf

I would like to replace the print statement below with a `print(f"...")` statement.

```
score = 0.1234567
print('Accuracy: {:.2f}%.'.format(score * 100))
```

How do I combine the `{:.2f}` and the `score * 100` to form something like this

```
 print(f'Accuracy {:.2f score*100}%.) # not working
```

Can someone point me into the right direction?

Comment: `{score*100:.2f}`